# A question about PriorityQuery application

Tags: java, priority-queue

I wondoner is it possible to implement priority query to solve following question: Suppose there is a school which needs to regulate its maximum current students due to the pandemic. For example, there are 4 lessons on some day, which are 9:00-11:00 with 50 students, 10:00-12:00 with 25 students, 14:00-16:00 with 60 students and 17:00-18:00 with 70 students. Then the maximum current students is 75 because when it is 10:00-11:00 there are 75 students in total taking lessons. My initial idea is to create two priority queue, one takes lesson start time as priority and another takes lesson end time. Can some one give any suggestions about this?

Comment: I don't see how using times as the priority is going to solve anything.

Comment: I think this resembles with merge interval problem..

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array where each index will represent an hour. And each element will be an integer representing how many MORE students are allowed in the school during this time.

For example array element with index 0 - represents 00:00, 22 - 23:00.

Then the array for your example will look like that:

`[0(0:00),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50(9:00),25(10:00),-50(11:00),-25(12:00),0,60(14:00),0,-60(16:00),70(17:00),-70(18:00),0,0,0,0,0]`

And then when you need to know the number of students allowed at particular hour, you need to simply sum the array element up to the particular HOUR(index).

For example for 11:00 it will be 0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+50+25=75.

Or when you insert the elements, you can as well update the rest of the array, to calculate the exact capacity for each hour. Then you don't have to calculate sum every time you need to know the number of allowed students. Your data structure will already content precalculated the values.
The array would look like that:
`[0(0:00),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50(9:00),75(10:00),25(11:00),0(12:00),0,60(14:00),0,0(16:00),70(17:00),0(18:00),0,0,0,0,0]`

This is a trade of to make between slow selects vs slow inserts.